# Running Java jar on remote machine in Fire and forget way

Tags: java, windows, ssh

I want to run my java jar on remote machine by establishing an SSH connection. I am able to run jar but I am unable to close SSH session until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Below is my batch file to run the jar. Batch file name is Run_service.bat

`@ECHO off
java.exe -jar D:\NSXJarfiles\BulkSolve-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
exit`

Trying to execute the jar from SSH session using below command

`ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l userid IP "D:/Scripts/Run_Service.bat"`

so I established ssh session and I am able to run the jar file in session.

The service started on port.

But once the service started, I have to close the ssh session but it's not closing until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Below is the image for the same the service started in ssh session. I tried many things but nothing worked. Please help me to figure out a way to do the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`@ECHO off
START /B javaw.exe -jar D:\NSXJarfiles\BulkSolve-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
exit`

Comment: javaw.exe not solved the problem it also started the service on console not in background and my ssh session also not closed.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: No luck its not worked.

Comment: your ssh connection is not getting closed?
can you explain a bit what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If i am running the batch file manually or from command prompt its starting but when i am triggering it from SSH session ssh session terminated after triggering the batch file but service not started.

Comment: If i am using java -jar xxx.jar in batch and triggering batch file from SSH it starts the service in SSH session only and the SSH session is not closing until i press CRTL+C , But i have to open SSH session from jenkins container it have to terminate once it starts the java service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no free lunch; if you want to run an app an as a service, you're going to have to install the app as a service.  That way if the OS is restarted your application comes back without human intervention.  It also allows you to disconnect from the SSH server and have the process continue to run. (You could also try `cmd /c javaw.exe -jar D:\NSXJarfiles\BulkSolve-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but if the process dies, it's not coming back)

For spring boot, check out the [Windows Services](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-windows) section of the reference, which points you to [winsw](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw), and a [seperately maintained example](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-boot-daemon) to describe how to bring it all together